# VBA Message box to work through a filtered selection of data

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a macro that I can run on a worksheet that uses autofilters. In an ideal world my macro should display a message box that gives me three options:

1) Run a specific set of VBA instructions (in the code below it is to colour cell B2) on the first visible row (ignoring the header) then move to the next visible row and display the message box again.
2) Skip this row, find the next visible row and display the message box again.
3) Quit the macro.

I have the bare bones of the macro below however I feel I'm missing some clever way of displaying the message box again after the first two buttons are pressed. Also I'm not convinced by my code to end the macro.

FYI: The reason for the message box rather than a flat out looped macro is that the filters regularly change and I'm looking to reduce the need to rewrite the code based on the necessary filters.

```
Sub Msg_exe()
    Dim Option_Menu As Integer
    Dim strMsg As String
    Dim strTitle As String

    Range("B2").Select
    strMsg = "Continue with this row"
    strTitle = "Alert"

    Option_Menu = MsgBox(strMsg, vbYesNoCancel + vbQuestion, strTitle)

    Select Case Option_Menu
        Case 6 'code to colour the cell goes here
            Selection.Font.ColorIndex = 25
            Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 33
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
            Do While ActiveCell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
                ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
            Loop
            'I need some code to show the message box again ready for the next row

        Case 7 'code to skip to the next visable line goes here
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
            Do While ActiveCell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
                ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
            Loop
            'I need some code to show the message box again ready for the next row

        Case 2 'the code to end the macro goes here (I hope this is correct)
            End 
    End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the rows, beginning at whichever row you decide, and ascertain if the calculation is required thereafter (I haven't tested so please check this matches your requirements first):

```
Sub Msg_exe()

    Dim cur_row as long
    Dim Option_Menu As Integer
    Dim strMsg As String
    Dim strTitle As String

    For cur_row = 2 to Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row 'Modify this row referenced to suit

        if not Range("B" & cur_row).EntireRow.Hidden then

            Range("B" & cur_row).Select
            strMsg = "Continue with this row"
            strTitle = "Alert"

            Option_Menu = MsgBox(strMsg, vbYesNoCancel + vbQuestion, strTitle)

            Select Case Option_Menu
                Case 6 'code to colour the cell goes here
                    Selection.Font.ColorIndex = 25
                    Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 33
                Case 7 'code to skip to the next visible line goes here
                Case 2 'the code to end the macro goes here (I hope this is correct)
                    Exit Sub
            End Select

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Excellent. You have got is spot on, thanks so much for this.

Comment: Glad to help, if this solved your problem, I'd appreciate if you marked this answer as correct. Thanks